# Setting custom metadata for s3 objects using axios put method

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, axios, aws-api-gateway

I've been spinning my wheels on this all day.  I am working on a simple web app that allows the user to upload photos to an s3 bucket with included custom metadata (e.g. if I upload a photo of a man, I can include a label 'brother').  I'm using API Gateway with an S3 proxy.

The function successfully uploads the photos to the bucket.  However, I have been unable to successfully include the custom metadata.

I tried including the custom metadata in my headers when uploading the object, with the format 'x-amz-meta-'.  After sending the request I can confirm that the metadata is listed under request headers.

Below is my upload function:

```
function upload() {
  var path = (document.getElementById("uploaded_file").value).split("\\");
    console.log("Here is the path: ", path);

    customLabels = document.getElementById("custom_labels").value;
    console.log("Here are the custom labels: ", customLabels);

    var file_name = path[path.length - 1];
    console.log("The file name is: ", file_name);

    var file = document.getElementById("uploaded_file").files[0];
    console.log("Here is the file: ", file);
    console.log("Size of customLabels?", customLabels.length);
    
    if (customLabels.length != 0) {
            var headers = {
                    'Content-Type': file.type,
                    'x-amz-meta-customlabels': customLabels
            };
    } else {
            var headers = {
                    'Content-Type': file.type,
            };
    };

    console.log("The headers are: ", headers);

    url = "my apig gateway url" + file.name;

    axios.put(url, file, { headers: headers }).then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        alert("Image uploaded: " + file.name);
    }).catch(function(result) {
        console.log("result", result);
    });
}
```

Comment: are you sure you're passing the headers through to s3?

Comment: i don't think that i am, but i'm not sure how to accomplish this - can i do this in the api gateway console?

Comment: ah i seem to have got it! included a mapping template in my integration request.  thanks for your question, helped me realize what the issue was.